# Difference between datacontext and normal object creation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, c#-4.0, mvvm

I have seen a video where at different windows, the presenter follows different styles.

For instance:

In one window, he uses like this below:

```
EmployeeViewModel evm = (EmployeeViewModel)this.DataContext;
evm.Display();
```

In another, he uses like:

```
EmployeeViewModel evm = new EmployeeViewModel();
evm.Display();
```

Whats the difference technically and the best way to use ? Please help me understand the difference.

Comment: Somebody voted it negative :0 I don't know the difference in meaning behind these two styles :(

Comment: It is probably not a very good video, because the naming is very poor. I'd suggest you read more about the `MVVM` pattern, because using `DataContext` is an essential part of `MVVM`.

Comment: @Silvermind: Hi, well sorry, the video might be good, really I learnt something. Its by one of the Silverlight folk from MS, looks like. Anyway, concept is of main concern here. Well, I experimented changing style said above and I think, they both are not for achieving same goal. To some extent, I see there is no relation, yet dont understand completely. Well, will go through more C# concepts and MVVM videos and books, thank you Silvermind :) I liked your ID name :P :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code fragment retrieves the currently displayed ViewModel. (It should do a null-check)

The second code fragment creates a new instance of a ViewModel.

Because it is not clear what Display() does, it is hard to explain the difference between the  effect of the two fragments but it could be that the second fragment is a (unit)test of the ViewModel which ignores the View.

There is no best way as far as I can see because both fragments serve a different purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much Erno, yes both serves different purpose. The meaning of second one, I am very familiar with. However, the first one although I used at certain places, I don't very well understand its meaning in depth. Well, will study further to understand it better. Thank you so much again :)

Comment: Sorry, I misrepresented. The video says like this: EmployeeViewModel evm = new EmployeeViewModel();
            evm.GetEmployees();
            myView.DataContext = evm;

Comment: This creates an instance of the ViewModel, loads data into the ViewModel and then makes it available to the View to display. I consider the call to GetEmployees() to be not very clean. I'd GetEmployees to return employees, instead it loads employees.

Comment: Perfectly said, thank you Erno, thats what happening in my VS andd the video also explained the same. However, the 1st one I got confused as the naming of object he used same name. I thought that, since name of object between one and two in my post above is same, behavior should also be same. Well anyway, I will try to understand the 1st one. Cheers :)